# Property / field initializers in code generation

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, properties, initializer

I'm generating code in a visual studio extension using CodeDom and plain code strings. My extension reads a current classes declared fields and properties using reflection and generates contructors, initializers, implements certain interfaces, etc.

The generator class is simple:

```
public class CodeGenerator < T >  
{  
    public string GetCode ()  
    {  
        string code = "";  
        T type = typeof(T);  
        List < PropertyInfo > properties = t.GetProperties();  
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)  
            code += "this." + property.Name + " = default(" + property.PropertyType.Name + ")";  
    }  
}
```

I'm stuck at field and property initializers in two ways.

Firstly, although `default(AnyNonGenericValueOrReferenceType)` seems to work in most cases, I'm uncomfortable with using it in generated code.

Secondly, it does not work for generic types since I can't find a way to get the underlying type of the generic type. So if a property is `List < int >`, `property.PropertyType.Name` returns `` List`1 ``. There are two problems here. First, I need to get the proper name for the generic type without using string manipulation. Second, I need to access the underlying type. The full property type name returns something like:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

Comment: Could you elaborate why are uncomfortable with using `default(T)`?

Comment: It's not a showstopper but I'd rather use CodeDom to generate an initializer that general users would be familiar with. There are still a LOT of developers who haven't come across a depth of generics where you would stumble upon the default(T) construct.

Comment: And why are you even generating this code? All fields are set to the default value before the constructor runs. And this includes backing fields of autoproperties.

Comment: Please see my comment on the answer below.

Comment: I'm trying out both approaches and will mark the answer accordingly. Thanks both. Can we mark more than one answer as correct by the way?

Comment: By the way, I was a paid member with experts-exchange and switched to stackoverflow recently. It's invaluable but formatting code for questions is a royal pain. Any of you veterans have advice? :)

Comment: For those interested, I've launched a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814508/reflect-generate-compile-execute-disassemble-decompile-reflect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure you want to use strings, you will have to write your own method to format those type names. Something like:

```
static string FormatType(Type t)
{
    string result = t.Name;

    if (t.IsGenericType)
    {
        result = string.Format("{0}<{1}>",
            result.Split('`')[0],
            string.Join(",", t.GetGenericArguments().Select(FormatType)));
    }

    return result;
}
```

This code assumes you have all necessary `using`s in your file.

But I think it's much better to actually use CodeDOM's object model. This way, you don't have to worry about `using`s, formatting types or typos:

```
var statement =
    new CodeAssignStatement(
        new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), property.Name),
        new CodeDefaultValueExpression(new CodeTypeReference(property.PropertyType)));
```

And if you really don't want to use `default(T)`, you can find out whether the type is a reference or value type. If it's a reference type, use `null`. If it's value type, the default constructor has to exist, and so you can call that.

Comment: Thanks. I will give your CodeDom a try to see how it fares with generic reference types. I have a feeling I'll get stuck with nested generics though.

Comment: So far, the first approach worked perfectly. I added the full namespace and got: `System.Collections.Generic.List < System.Collections.Generic.List < Entity > >`. How could I fully qualify `Entity` as well? Will now try CodeDom to see if it will handle generating correct calls to complex constructors.

Comment: By the way, in case I did not clarify, I do NOT want to set reference types to null. When properties are marked with certain custom attributes (specially collections), they need to be created only once in the constructor. The reflection approach works very well for inserting the correct type declarations.

Comment: Argh! Why did I not guess CodeDom would do exactly the same thing. Is there no way to programatically determine the default constructor (if none are explicitly defined) and generate the code to call it? Or one of the explicitly defined for that matter. Am I wrong in assuming that reflection and codedom have a two-way relationship at compile-time? After all disassemblers do this don't they?

Comment: @RaheelKhan, I'm not sure what do you mean by two-way relationship. But you can certainly use reflection to find out whether a type has a parameterless constructor and then use CodeDOM to generate code that calls it.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was looking for. I guess it'll take some more toying with reflection and codedom to be able to do this without an SO marathon. By a two-way relationship, I meant C# code can be parsed to a structure using reflection and back to code through codedom.

Comment: Also, your answer implies it would be possible to find constructor overloads with parameters and generate code against them as well.

Comment: Sure it would. Look at [the `Type` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) to see what's possible with reflection. For information about constructors, you can use the `GetContructor()` or `GetConstructors()` methods.

Comment: That did it. Reference to the third comment on this answer, could you please tell me how I could update the `FormatType` method code to fully qualify the type within `< >` brackets. I managed to qualify the outer name.

Answer (score 2):

Before I try to answer, I feel compelled to point out that what you're doing seems redundant. Assuming that you are putting this code into a constructor, generating something like:

```
public class Foo
{
  private int a;
  private bool b;
  private SomeType c;

  public Foo()
  {
    this.a = default(int);
    this.b = default(bool);
    this.c = default(SomeType);
  }
}
```

is unnecessary. That *already happens automatically* when a class is constructed. (In fact, some quick testing shows that these assignments aren't even optimized away if they're done explicitly in the constructor, though I suppose the JITter could take care of that.)

Second, the `default` keyword was designed in large part to do exactly what you're doing: to provide a way to assign the "default" value to a variable whose type is unknown at compile time. It was introduced for use by generic code, I assume, but auto-generated code is certainly correct in using it as well.

Keep in mind that the `default` value of a reference type is `null`, so

```
this.list = default(List<int>);
```

does not construct a new `List<int>`, it just sets `this.list` to `null`. What I suspect you want to do, instead, is to use the `Type.IsValueType` property to leave value types at their default values, and initialize reference types using `new`.

Lastly, I think what you're looking for here is the [`IsGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isgenerictype.aspx) property of the `Type` class and the corresponding [`GetGenericArguments()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) method:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)  
{
  if (property.Type.IsGenericType)
  {
    var subtypes = property.Type.GetGenericArguments();
    // construct full type name from type and subtypes.
  }
  else
  {
    code += "this." + property.Name + " = default(" + property.PropertyType.Name + ")";  
  }
}
```

EDIT:

As far as constructing something useful for a reference type, a common technique I've seen used by generated code is to require a parameterless constructor for any class that you expect to use. It's easy enough to see if a class has a parameterless constructor, by calling `Type.GetConstructor()`, passing in an empty `Type[]` (e.g. `Type.EmptyTypes`), and see if it returns a `ConstructorInfo` or `null`. Once that has been established, simply replacing `default(typename)` with `new typename()` should achieve what you need.

More generally you can supply any array of types to that method to see if there's a matching constructor, or call `GetConstructors()` to get them all. Things to look out for here are the `IsPublic`, `IsStatic`, and `IsGenericMethod` fields of the `ConstructorInfo`, to find one you can actually call from wherever this code is being generated.

The problem you are trying to solve, though, is going to become arbitrarily complex unless you can place some constraints on it. One option would be to find an arbitrary constructor and build a call that looks like this:

```
var line = "this." + fieldName + " = new(";
foreach ( var param in constructor.GetParameters() )
{
  line += "default(" + param.ParameterType.Name + "),";
}
line = line.TrimEnd(',') + ");"
```

(Note this is for illustrative purposes only, I'd probably use CodeDOM here, or at least a StringBuilder :)

But of course, now you have the problem of determining the appropriate type name for each parameter, which themselves could be generics. And the reference type parameters would all be initialized to null. And there's no way of knowing which of the arbitrarily many constructors you can pick from actually produces a usable object (some of them may do bad things, like assume you're going to set properties or call methods immediately after you construct an instance.)

How you go about solving those issues is not a technical one: you can recursively apply this same logic to each parameter as far down as you're willing to go. It's a matter of deciding, for your use case, how complex you need to be and what kind of limits you're willing to place on the users.

Comment: What kind of Code Analysis are you talking about?

Comment: side-note: anyone know how to escape the backticks in SEML?

Comment: huh. Well, I was talking about Visual Studio's CA1805, "Do not initialize unnecessarily"; but it appears that they have removed that particular rule from VS2010. Dunno why, it's still needless code. *shrug*

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield, you definitely understood what I'm trying to do here. Regarding redundancy, this situation calls for conformation rather than optimization. I can see how you, as a user, would expect an extension to generate the most optimized code. In my case, however, I'm using the extension to ensure adherence to conventions. At a later stage in development, we use our own code profilers to ensure optimization.

Comment: @RaheelKhan, I think not writing code that does nothing is more about optimization for the reader than performance.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield, your answer and even the revision history explains a lot. Good to have insight. The end problem however remains unsolved. How to generate a contextually correct constructor call. Since `default(T)` sets reference types to null, that is not an option. If you want to know more about why I want to do this, I'd be glad to explain. However, the call to `new T()` is a must. Would you know how to get the implicit constructor or a list of explicit constructors with correct parameters and generate the code to call them?

Comment: Blargh. I just checked the edit history and noticed it removed a bunch of my edits. I am clearly Stack Overflow Impaired this week.

Comment: That answers the question but the insight is invaluable. Thank you again. SO should allow multiple up votes per user per answer as comments progress.

Comment: As for constraints, since I control the architecture and conventions where this code generator will be applied, the complexity can be controlled. Even the pattern of constructors can be enforced in virtually all cases. Classes that simply cannot conform to such constraints can be attribute marked for exclusion and sent off for code review.